# Reznor UDP-60 - Need C Wire

Tags: thermostat-c-wire

I read the following but my situation is slightly different: [Wifi Thermostat to Reznor Garage Heater. No "C" wire connection on terminal strip](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/75684/wifi-thermostat-to-reznor-garage-heater-no-c-wire-connection-on-terminal-stri)  He had an unused wire connected to W2.

I want to change the stat to one that requires a C wire.  Installer used 18-3 and connected Red to R, Green to G & White to W1.  Short of running new or more wire, do I have any other options?

Does the 24V have to come from the Reznor?

Thank you[image][image][image]

Comment: Please include pics of _your_ wiring - both at the thermostat and at the furnace. You can [edit] your post, then just drop the pics in and the site will upload and host them for you.

Comment: Yes, can you post photos of both ends of *your* wiring situation?

Comment: Also, you're 100% sure you don't have a spare wire hiding back at the end of the cable jacket I take it?

Comment: No spare, just 18-3. Installer saved a bunch on that job! Not sure if my follow-up post (edit) made it here: the red wire has continous 28v and the stat side picture is of non Wi-Fi stat that I want to replace. Thank you for your time and input.

Comment: Also, if the C on terminal strip was designated for C wire duties, shouldn't it read 28V continuously? Don't think it does. Will check schematic & probably ask installer.

Answer (score 0):

### Pick your poison

You have two options for solving this, but both of them are going to be a bit more inelegant than pulling a new thermostat cable.  Either you can use a gizmo that "multiplexes" two signals over the same wire to free up the third wire for C-wire duty (there are several out there, with different installation instructions, so you'll need to follow the directions for what you purchase), or you can supply 24VAC from an additional class 2 transformer either plugged into a nearby receptacle or hardwired to the faceplate of a nearby junction box, removing the jumper between Rh and Rc then landing the new 24VAC source on Rc and C when you do this.